# How to change the background color of excel data label using C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to change the shape of excel [**data label**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-format-of-data-labels-in-a-chart-ee7525e3-3a58-4142-b0e3-8140a1d6545e) using C#. But I am stuck with interop [**Fill Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.datalabel.fill.aspx).

Not able to understand at all how to use it and also how can I change the shape of data label using this. If anyone has any idea Please help.

Your help will be appreciated. I am using it in Line chart.

I have tried this so far-

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator iEChartSeries = seriesCollection.GetEnumerator();
if(iEChartSeries.MoveNext()){
    var oSeries = (Excel.Series)(iEChartSeries.Current);
    Excel.Points pts = (Excel.Points) oSeries.Points(Type.Missing);
    System.Collections.IEnumerator iPoints = pts.GetEnumerator();
    while(iPoints.MoveNext())
    {
        var pt = (Excel.Point)(iPoints.Current);
        pt.HasDataLabel = true;
        pt.DataLabel.Position = Excel.XlDataLabelPosition.xlLabelPositionAbove;

        pt.DataLabel.Font.Name = "Arial";
        pt.DataLabel.Font.FontStyle = "Bold";
        pt.DataLabel.Font.Size = 8;   
        pt.DataLabel.Text = "N";    
        pt.DataLabel.Fill = ????;//here I am stuck
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you work with the solution mentioned in this?

Comment: @creyD i am talking about data-label not cells and about background color of data-labels not color only.

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn´t see this..

Comment: Ok Please remove flag

Answer (score 1):

Your line: `pt.DataLabel.Fill = ????; //here I am stuck`

You need this: `pt.DataLabel.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ???`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.datalabel.fill.aspx

In this link it is saying `it returns a specified shape`. Can you please help me to find how to use these shapes/?

Comment: The best thing I can say to a C# guy is to look at the VBA page, and the code will be very very similar: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vba/excel-vba/articles/datalabel-object-excel